# Use concurrent.futures with tornado event loop?

Tags: python, concurrency, tornado, concurrent.futures

How can occasionally use threads and futures within a Tornado application?

My server occasionally needs to run long-runnings tasks in a separate thread or process (the task releases the GIL.)  I would like to do this with a concurrent.futures exectutor

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
future = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

How can I integrate this future into the Tornado event loop?  Ideally this integration plays well with `tornado.gen` coroutines.  I want to yield from the future without blocking on it.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Ideally I would like to yield from a `concurrent` `Future`.

I'm looking for a function `f` that makes the following possible

```
@gen.coroutine
def my_coroutine(...)
    ...
    future = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
    result = yield f(future)
```

Comment: It's just suppose to work, according to the docs, tornado's Future is compatible with concurrent.futures http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html

Comment: I believe that the compatibility discussed there goes the other way.

Comment: It doesn't really makes sense for it to be the other way, because you can't push a Tornado future to an existing concurrent.futures pool. What happens when you try yield future (without any f)

Comment: Ah, @a-jesse-jiry-davis 's response below corroborates your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a special `f` function at all, simply yield the Future that `executor.submit` returns:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

@gen.coroutine
def my_coroutine(...)
    ...
    future = executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs)
    result = yield future
```